# Gluing together solutions to differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Edit**. *This question hasn't received much interest so far. Please leave suggestions for improvement in the comments.*

Suppose we're wanting to glue together solutions to a differential equation to obtain a solution on a larger domain. Let $S(X)$ denote the set of all solutions with domain $X,$ where $X$ is allowed to be any open set.

Now I imagine that:

**Conjecture 1.** For all open sets $X$ and $Y$ and solutions $f \in S(X)$ and $g \in S(Y)$, we have that if $f$ and $g$ agree when restricted to the domain $X \cap Y$, then $f \cup g \in S(X \cup Y).$

Is this actually true? If not, how do we fix the assertion?

A related question about uniqueness. I believe that:

**Conjecture 2.** If $X$ is not only open, but also connected, then for all $f,g \in S(X)$ we have that if $f$ and $g$ agree on some non-empty open subset of $X$, then $f=g$.

Is this actually true? If not, how do we fix the assertion?